# Using user controls with Ajax within asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, wpf

I have an asp.net application in which i have nested master pages. The problem is that i have many difficulties to use an update panel to refresh only a part of the page in a child master page or a web form which inherits from a master page different of the parent one. I think this problem is caused by my use of update panel in the parent master page . So , because I worked with the user controls in WPF application and i'm using to put a container which its contents( which is a user control) changes dynamically when i need to, i wonder if i have two user controls ( login and inscription for example ) and i have this code in my view :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                           //putting a user control
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

- How can i change dynamically the user control  used in the update panel?
- Is it a good approach to do like this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.contenttemplate.aspx) states:

> To add items to the UpdatePanel control dynamically, use the
>   ContentTemplateContainer property, which enables you to add child
>   controls without having to create a custom template that implements
>   the ITemplate interface.

1. I found that anytime I try to use the UpdatePanel, it ends up causing tons of problems. I've found using AJAX (with jQuery to make it easier) to be a much better solution.

Comment: I have tried this example http://partialupdatepanel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PartialUpdatePanel/Control/PartialUpdatePanel.cs but i have always this error "PartialUpdatePanel.ashx" is not found !!!!

Comment: When you get that error, it means exactly what it says. It can't find it. Make sure it can find it.